# My Chinese Laoshi gave me a Chinese name "玉意" I don't know what it means

Tags: translation

My Chinese Laoshi gave me a Chinese name "玉意" I don't know what it means.. if anyone knows what my chinese name means... can you please explain to me?? My mandarin is still very limited so I could not ask my Laoshi directly...

Answer (score 4):

玉意, I assume you are female?

There was an actress of the same name in the 50s.

[https://baike.baidu.com/item/容玉意](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E5%AE%B9%E7%8E%89%E6%84%8F)

Maybe your Laoshi is a fan.

Anyway, 玉意 could be translated many ways depending on how 玉, (jadeite) is interpreted.

Besides being a semi-precious stone worn as jewellery it is revered by the Chinese, and in their culture jade symbolizes nobility, perfection, constancy, immortality, purity.

"The wise have likened jade to virtue. For them, its polish and brilliancy represent the whole of purity; its perfect compactness and extreme hardness represent the sureness of intelligence; its angles, which do not cut, although they seem sharp, represent justice; the pure and prolonged sound, which it gives forth when one strikes it, represents music" -- 礼记 -- "Book of Rites", (Zhou dynasty -- 1046 until 771 BC, (周; pinyin: Zhōu)

So Jade is more than a stone. Thus the meaning to be put to 玉 in your name would be nobility, perfection, constancy, immortality, purity. Take your pick.

Finally, 意 too could mean many things or meanings. But let's take the one which, to my mind, (no pun intended), is most suited to combine with 玉, and that is "thought"

So, 玉意 could mean "nobility, perfection, constancy, purity of thought"

Comment: yes I am a woman, my chinese full name is 王玉意 does the name sound strange or weird?

Answer (score 1):

As my answer is rather long, I'll comment here.

王玉意, your given name is neither strange nor weird. Don't you trust your Laoshi?

王, or in pinyin, "Wáng"; also pronounced "Wong", (Cantonese), and "Ong", (Hokkien), is a very common surname. It is also very ancient as one might expect because it has the meaning of "monarch", or anything imperial. A famous figure from ancient China, 王昭君, (Wáng zhāo Jūn), was known as one of the Four Beauties of ancient China. Born in the Western Han dynasty (206 BC–8 AD), she was usually depicted as a "p'i-p'a", (琵琶), player, a four-stringed musical instrument, like a guitar.

Given my answer on 玉意, (with 玉 having 王 in there as well), the whole name 王玉意 is both graphically strong and intrinsically powerful.

Your Laoshi certainly has high expectations for you as you could say the whole name means -- "Imperial purity of thoughts"

BTW, is your Laoshi Cantonese? Because 王玉意 sounds "smoother", easier on the tongue, when pronounced in Cantonese.

Here is a musical tribute to 王昭君:-

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hff4jzAdBNs

It'll take years later for you to understand the song, but at least you'll get to hear how 王昭君 is pronounced.

Good Luck on your learning journey.

Answer (score 0):

the name “玉意” is, . . . a little bit “odd”, imo

“意” means “idea, opinion, sentiment, . .”

“玉” only, means “jade”, “gem”, “precious stone”.

however, when it’s placed before another character, it would means “a honorific adjective of addressing someone’s body, speech & beheviour” (尊稱他人的身體或言行)

> 尊稱他人的身體或言行。如：「玉體」、「玉照」。三國魏．曹植〈七啟〉：「將敬滌耳，以聽玉音。」

http://dict.revised.moe.edu.tw/cgi-bin/cbdic/gsweb.cgi?o=dcbdic&searchid=W00000011670

so, the first “association” i have, when hearing this term, is “someone’s respectable opinion”

last, rejecting one’s teacher’s recommendation is, . . . not good.

have fun :)

Comment: the full name that my teacher gave me is 王玉意 , does it sound weird ???

Comment: @littlesunflowerfield, depends on your original full name 